# QThread and QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer

I'm working on an application developed with Qt 4.6.

I want to create a custom timer that counts in a separate thread. However, I want this timer to be able to send signals to the main thread.

I subclassed QThread but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is Timer.h:

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtCore/QThread>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>

class Timer : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Timer(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Timer();

    // true if the timer is active
    bool isCounting();

    // start the timer with a number of seconds
    void startCounting(int value = 300);
    void stopCounting();

    // the number of seconds to reach
    int maximum();

    // the current value of the timer
    int value();

    // elapsed time since the timer has started
    int elapsedTime();

signals:
    // sent when the timer finishes to count
    void timeout();
    // an event is emited at each second when the timer is active
    void top(int remainingSeconds);

protected:
    // launch the thread
    //virtual void run();

private slots:
    // decrements the remaining time at each second and emits top()
    void timerEvent();

private:
    QTimer* _timer;
    // remaining time
    int _left;
    // number of seconds at timer startup
    int _maximum;
};

#endif // TIMER_H
```

And Timer.cpp:

```
#include "Timer.h"

Timer::Timer(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    _timer = new QTimer(this);
    _maximum = 0;
    _left = 0;
    connect(_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerEvent()));
}

Timer::~Timer()
{
    delete _timer;
}

bool Timer::isCounting()
{
    // test if timer still active
    return _timer->isActive();
}

void Timer::startCounting(int value)
{
    qDebug() << QString("Start timer for %1 secs").arg(QString::number(value));
    if(_left != 0 || _timer->isActive())
    {
         _timer->stop();
    }

    _maximum = value;
    _left = value;

    // emit the first top
    emit top(_left);

    // start the timer: 1000 msecs
    _timer->start(1000);

    // start the thread
    start();
}

void Timer::stopCounting()
{
    qDebug() << QString("Stopping timer at %1 secs => %2 secs remaining.").arg(QString::number(elapsedTime()), QString::number(_left));
    // stop timer
    _timer->stop();
    _left = 0;
    _maximum = 0;
    // kill thread
    terminate();
}

int Timer::maximum()
{
    return _maximum;
}

int Timer::value()
{
    return _left;
}

void Timer::timerEvent()
{
    qDebug() << "Timer event";
    if(--_left == 0)
    {
        // stop timer
        _timer->stop();
        // emit end of timer
        emit timeout();
        // stop thread
        terminate();
    }
    else
    {
        // emit a signal at each second
        emit top(_left);
    }
}

int Timer::elapsedTime()
{
    return (_maximum - _left);
}
```

**EDIT**

I realized the object I tried to move to another thread was actually a singleton. It could lead to a problem ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Implementation)).

Comment: What problem/issue you are facing ?

Comment: timerEvent() is never triggered.

Comment: How would it without a running event loop on the thread it lives in?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to subclass QThread in this particular case. And in general, abstain from subclassing QThread unless you are sure it is what you need.

Here is a quick example how to setup a worker and timer in a thread and launch it:

the worker class:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

signals:
    void doSomething();

public slots:
    void trigger() {
        emit doSomething();
    }
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainThreadObject o;

    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    Worker w;
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1000);

    timer.moveToThread(thread);
    w.moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), &timer, SLOT(start()));
    QObject::connect(&w, SIGNAL(doSomething()), &o, SLOT(doSomething()));
    QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &w, SLOT(trigger()));

    thread->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

So, we have the `MainThreadObject` which represents a QObject derived living in the main thread. We create the timer and `Worker` object, which is just used to wrap a signal and slot to avoid the need of subclassing QThread. The timer is setup and it and the worker are moved to the new thread, the thread `started()` signal is connected to the timer `start()` slot, the worker `doSomething()` signal is connected to the main thread object `doSomething()` slot, and finally the timer `timeout()` signal is connected to the worker `trigger()` slot. Then the thread is started which initiates the entire chain in the event loop.

As a result, the `MainThreadObject::doSomething()` is called every second, with the signal emitted from the secondary thread.

Comment: I wanted to create a generic timer I can reuse.
My application is quite complex. It sends ActiveX requests to a specific hardware. Then the application has to wait either a signal from the hardware or the end of the timer. I am not sure your solution would work in my case.

Comment: It will work, don't worry. It saves you the subclassing, you can keep all your custom stuff in the `Worker` object instance. You could move the timer inside the worker class.

Comment: I didn't want the timer and the worker to be in the same thread. The worker can be blocked sometimes. Will the timer still be able to count?

Comment: If the timer is in the same thread as the worker and the worker does something heavy, it will block the event loop, so no. But if you have a heavy workload, you can use the same design pattern to create a new thread and new worker object, send it to do the work and then only inform the `Worker` that it is done to redirect to the main thread.

Comment: Note that you can do this all in the main thread, the timer itself does no heavy work so it doesn't need to be in a new thread as long as you don't block the main thread. I just did this example to show you how to put the timer in a new thread in case that is what you need, since that is what you asked for.

Comment: Yes you pointed a good point. My timer doesn't need to be in a new thread. But the my Worker does obviously. So I think I will keep the timer in the main thread. Can you confirm that signals can be sent between the main thread and the Worker's thread? (I'm sorry I'm quite new to Qt)

Comment: @Maxbester - yes, when you do connections without specifying the connection type, Qt checks if both objects live in the same thread, if so it uses a direct connection, if not, the connection is queued. The only thing you should keep in mind is that if you want to pass a parameter through a queued connection, it needs to be registered as a meta type using `qRegisterMetaType()` if it is not already.

Comment: I tried your solution with the timer in the main thread and the worker in its own thread but it looks like both are still in the same thread. I added some trace in the timer and when the Worker is blocked, the timer doesn't write anything. Could I miss something? I used qRegisterMetaType() to register my timer and the calling class. Does the Worker have to be registered to?

Comment: Did you by any chance instantiate by providing a parent? QObject with parent cannot be moved to a different thread. You don't need to register your worker, you only need to register a type you plan on sending from one thread to another via a signal/slot connection.

Comment: I only send QString and int from one thread to another. Should I register them even if they are basic types?

Comment: According to `QMetaType::isRegistered()` both QString and int are registered.

Comment: This is very strange... `QThread::currentThread();` returns the same address in both threads :(

Comment: Oh I realize the object I try to move to another thread is actually a singleton. It may cause a problem. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&timer, "start", Qt::QueuedConnection); //timer->start()
```

if you want to start timer immediately

Or

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&timer, "start", Qt::QueuedConnection , Q_ARG(int, 1000 )); //timer->start(200)
```

if you want to start timer after 1000s

In the Non-GUI thread (QThread or Pthread Callback)

Answer (score 0):

First, if you subclass from QThread, you have to implement run() method, if not, there is no point of doing that, you can inherit from QObject instead.

Second, your QTimer has to reside in a thread that runs an event loop. Without an event loop no Qt queued signals can be transmitted. You can launch an event loop by calling exec() in thread's run method:

```
void Timer::run() {
    exec();
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot to implement run(). I tried the run method you provided but it doesn't work. It looks like the thread is never created because the timer counts once the main thread is free.

Comment: Actually, you do not need to reimplement run(), because its default implementation just runs exec() as shown. And you can simply make a QThread instance like ddriver does in his answer. My point was, that there is no need inherit from QThread in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

Probable reason can be, your timer object is not in a thread with event loop. Event loop is required to trigger the signals.

However, I would suggest that you should not go with this approach. Timers use different mechanism on different platform and your code might not behave as expected on different platform.