# Can I use QTimer to replace QThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

More precisely, the question should be:

***What's the difference between connecting the signal*** `QTimer::timeout` ***to my working function and creating a worker thread with*** `QThread`?

---

I am writing a program which receives streaming data in main thread (the signal is generated by `QIODevice::readread()`)and processes them concurrently. For now I start a `QTimer` constantly firing signal `QTimer::timeout`, and the signal is connected to a working function in main thread which does the data processing stuff. This is how I achieve the concurrency.

I wonder if this approach different from creating another thread with `QThread`, since the idea I've found in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835267/qthread-and-qtimer) is very simliar to what I've done. The only difference is that the accepted answer creates another thread and moves timer and worker class on it. Besides the difference, I can't see any necessity of using a thread in my case.

In my case (receiving data in main thread and processing them concurrently), am I doing OK using `QTimer` or should I create a `QThread`? I am quite new to multi-threading, and if I misunderstand something, please help correct me. Thank you.

---

**[Edit]:**

I don't know what's the difference/advantage of creating a new thread to process the data. For now, everything is doing in one thread: I keep storing data in a queue and dequeue them one by one in a function triggered by `QTimer::timeout`.

Comment: From where the `main thread` receives data? from another thread?

Comment: from the signal `QIODevice::readread()`. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: is the device running in separate thread? Do you want to process the data in main thread or in a new thread?

Comment: @RakibulHasan Thank you for asking. That's my problem. I don't know if I'll get a better result using a new thread. I also found my question unclear due to my lack of understanding. I've edited the post, please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
What's the difference between connecting the signal QTimer::timeout to my working 
function and creating a worker thread with QThread?
```

When you **connect** some signal/slot pair from the objects which has the **same** thread affinity, then the connection is *direct*. What it means is in your case, the main thread creates the `timer`, and also contains the `slot`, so the `signal` will be emitted in the `main` thread and also will be processed in the `main` thread (as the slot is also in the main thread).

When you **connect** some signal/slot pair from the objects which has the **different** thread affinity, then the connection is *queued*. That means *signal emission* and *slot execution* will run in different threads.

You are **not** really achieving concurrency, the *timer signal* and *processing* slot are executing in main thread sequentially.

So here are your options:

1. If you want to process data in main thread, current code is ok.
2. If you want to emit `timeout` in main thread and process data in different thread then create new class with the processing method and use [`moveToThread`](https://qt-project.org/search/tag/movetothread)  with object of that class.

The link you provided really has a different situation. In your case (correct me if I am wrong), you process data only when data is *available*, not just after a specified time. Your situation is much like traditional producer/consumer problem. My proposal is to not use `QTimer` at all. Instead create a new `class` with a `slot`which will process data. Then `emit` a signal from main thread when data is available, and connect if to the processing `slot`. You will achieve real concurrency. In this case you will need to implement locking for shared data access, it is easy in `Qt`, you can just use [QMutexLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html)

Comment: Thank you. It's informative to me, I wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: So I use `QTimer` to achieve the concurrency but it's not multi-threading. Can I make a conclusion that the concurrency doesn't need to be achieved by multi-threading?

Comment: Not at all, you are not achieving concurrency. The code runs in a single thread, which means runs sequentially. For concurrency `QThread`is a must. Check [this](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) to understand how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I think the "concurrency" is just how I feel.

Answer (score 3):

First, a little background:

One of the fundamental ideas behind [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) is that a thread can only do one thing at a time. It may be updating the GUI, or processing data, or communicating with a remote server, but it can't be doing all those things at once.

That's where multi-threading comes in. You probably want your computer to be doing many things at once (watching videos, browsing the web, listening to music, and writing code all at the same time). The computer allows you to do that by scheduling each of these tasks on a separate threads and switching between them in periodic intervals.

In the old days, before multi-core processors, this was achieved solely by [multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) (the processor would interrupt the currently executing thread, switch to another thread context and execute the other thread for a while before switching again). With modern processors, you can have several threads executing at the EXACT same time, one on each core. This is typically referred to as [multiprocessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing).

Now, back to your question:

A thread can only do one thing at a time and, if you use a timer, you are using the main (AKA GUI) thread to process your data. This thread is typically responsible for responding to OS events and updating the GUI (hence GUI thread). If you don't have a lot of data to process, it's typically OK to do so on the GUI thread. However, if the data processing time has a chance of growing, it is recommended to execute such processing on a separate thread to make sure that the UI remains responsive (and so that you don't get the annoying "Your program is not responding" message from the OS). Basically, if data processing can take longer than ~200ms, it is recommended to execute the processing on a separate thread so that the user doesn't feel like the GUI is "stuck".

Comment: My data processing also including an oscilloscope-like, dynamic data display and I found that the display of oscilloscope lags behind when I enlarge the screen of oscilloscope, so I think I put too many things in one thread and cause laggy, am I right in this case?

Comment: That could well be the case. The oscilloscope can't be updated or repainted when other data processing is taking place on the GUI thread.